# using object on *ngfor

Tags: json, angular, ionic3

I have an object with this structure:

```
departments = [{"id":"1","name":"department 1","active":"1"},{"id":"2","name":"department 2","active":"1"}]
```

And want it to fit here:

```
<ion-option *ngFor=" let departament of departments" [value]="departament['id']">{{departament['name']}}</ion-option>
```

But I'm compeletely unable to manipulate the object into something that will fit there

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you use / with maybe a json.parse before:

```
<ion-option *ngFor=" let departament of departments" [value]="departament.id">{{departament.name}}</ion-option>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use The `keyvalue` pipe if you are using angular 7. See an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyvalue-comparator